# How can I calculate the security level provided by a supersingular Elliptic Curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

I want to know what security level is provided by an elliptic curve used in [Supersingular isogeny Diffie–Hellman key exchange (SIDH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange). Is there any mathematical convention to follow or by looking at different parameters we can find the security level?

For instance, what security is provided by the type a and type d curves which are included in the [Charm crypto library](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm)?

I know the type a curve SS512 and SS1024 have a prime field of 512 and 1024 bits respectively. Can anyone tell me what security is provided by them?

Comment: @SEJPM Many thanks for your reply. Just a clarification this means the supersingular curves SS512 and SS1024 provides 256 and 512 bit-security respectively.

Comment: Wikipedia article linked indicates security bounds of $\mathcal{O}(p^{\frac{1}{4}})$, so if your $p$ is 512 bits $\approx 2^{512}$ that would mean you're getting no more than around $\approx 128$ bits security, not 256 as your comment implies..

Comment: @puzzlepalace Many thanks for your reply. One more question, is the key size same as the order of prime field i.e. in this case 512 bits?

Comment: @Aisha No. Uncompressed SIDH public keys are about $6\log_2p$ bits and private keys are something like $\frac12\log_2p$ bits.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/859

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/016.pdf Appendix of this paper states SS512 curve provides 80 bit security and SS1024 curve provides 112 bit security.

Comment: @satya Many Thanks for your reply, I will check the paper.